# Input Field with Undefined value after use document.forms.input.value to set its value

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular5, angular6

I'm developing an Angular Application and i need to edit the values from a array. So, i have my array that's showing in a Table, and when i click on a table line edit icon, it shows me the value of the field, in some inputs that are up to my table.

Like this:
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP85L.png].

But when i use the edit and save without changes, it turns the value of my input into undefined not keeping the same old value.
That's my code:

```
document.forms[0].serverAlias.value = alias;
document.forms[0].serverHost.value = host;
document.forms[0].netDataAddress.value = netData;
```

And my inputs:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="wrapper-upload item-block ">
        <label>Alias do Servidor</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="serverAlias" name="serverAlias" type="text" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="wrapper-upload item-block ">
        <label>Host do Servidor</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="serverHost" name="serverHost" type="text" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="wrapper-upload item-block ">
        <label>Endereço do NetData</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="netDataAddress" name="netDataAddress" type="text" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, i saw that if i click the field with mouse and click out it, when i save the edit it sends the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using objects and typing for data binding instead of using `documents.forms[0]...` and local variables :

```
public serverToEdit: {
    alias: string,
    host: string,
    netData: string
};
// now in your code instead of document.forms[0]... :
serverToEdit.alias = alias;
serverToEdit.host = host;
serverToEdit.netData = netData;
```

Your edition table should look like :

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="wrapper-upload item-block ">
        <label>Alias do Servidor</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="serverToEdit.alias" name="serverAlias" type="text" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="wrapper-upload item-block ">
        <label>Host do Servidor</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="serverToEdit.host" name="serverHost" type="text" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="wrapper-upload item-block ">
        <label>Endereço do NetData</label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="serverToEdit.netData" name="netDataAddress" type="text" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

When you save, you get your new values from the object `serverToEdit`.